# ansible execute shell script with differenr user

Tags: ansible

I am trying to execute shell script using ansible shell module as shown in below code

```
-name : Execute
 become_user: someuser
 shell:
   cmd: "./script.ksh"
   chdir: "/path/to/script"
```

But the script still uses my login instead of "someuser". How this can be fixed ?

Comment: Adding `become: yes`. Here you are just saying which user you should become if you were to use privilege escalation.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives

Comment: I am executing my playbook with sudo, do you think become: yes is nothing but sudo ?

Comment: Adding become: yes fixed my issues @β.εηοιτ.βε

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [@β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530) the `become: yes` is missing, see exapmles and explanation in [Become directives](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives).

> do you think become: yes is nothing but sudo ?

The default setting (atleast in my case) uses `sudo`.
To see the default `become_method` being used, check your "closest" [ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file) in the hierarchy.

You can run the playbook in [verbose mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-u) and by using `-vvv` increase verbosity to see the exact commands being used.

If the `become: yes` with `become_user: <username>` doesn't help try using a different `become_method`.

### Example with `su` and `su -`:

```
- name : Execute
  shell:
    cmd: "./script.ksh"
    chdir: "/path/to/script"
  become: yes
  become_user: someuser
  become_method: "su"
```

or:

```
- name : Execute
  shell:
   cmd: "su - someuser -c './script.ksh'"
   chdir: "/path/to/script"
  become: yes
```

In this case you will most likely recieve the following warning:

> [WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running su

Comment: Adding become: yes fixed my issue.